# Use all users in one cell in database

Tags: database, database-design

I have an assignment and struggling a bit. I am having a table called *EventTable* and inside it there is a column called *EventMembers* and its primary key is *EventID* and I am trying to have all the users(from *UserTable*) in one cell. Is something such possible? Can I create a row in *userId* called All which means all users will be included? Will that be ridiculous? 
Then can I use that *All* notation into *EventMembers*?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

As you talk about tables and columns, I suppose you are talking about relational databases. I suspect that you got the concept of implementing a 1-n relationship in such a database the wrong way round. If more than one person can take part in one event, but one person will take part in at most one event, you'll have

```
Person(id, name, event_id, ...)
Event(id, description, ...)
```

with the event id as foreign key on the n side of the 1:n relation. (There is a good convention to call a table like the functional objects contained in it in singular, so it should be called Event instead of EvenTable.)

If a person can take part in more than one event, you have an m:n relation that needs to be implemented by a separate table

```
Participation(id, event_id, person_id)
```

I don't quite realize what you mean by creating a row in userId, and what you try to achieve by that. The way described above is the textbook way of solving that kind of problem, and unless very special requirements are against this, it is safe to follow.

Things might be different if you use a non-relational database, but we would need a much more specific elaboration on your task to give advice for that.

Comment: yeah this is what is did precisely: I build a table called User and another table called Event(actually the table is larger it has 25 columns but here I am trying to find a relation between User and Event).The User table will be the one to contain sth from Event. Event has: eventId, eventTitle, eventDetails, eventDate, eventOffDate, eventMembers. My problem is: how to connect Event with User. It doesnt make sense becuase for ex: Independence day will be holiday for all of them. so how can I assign that to all the users?

Comment: An event that applies to everyone is, in database terms, totally different from an event that can be (and needs to be) related to some specific users. My solution had the second case in mind. For the everyone case, you don't need any database entries at all. Maybe just a boolean attribute at the event saying whether the event applies to everyone.

Comment: how can I do this inside Event table? I didnt get that point? Also how will I write this case in User table?